# Display a list of current tasks, future and past

Tags: website-design, lists, interface, web, task-flow

The user comes to perform the current task. If the task is done — the task goes to "done list"; if the task is skipped — it goes to "skipped list".

The current design has completed tasks indicated by <del>strikethrough</del> low contrast text, leaving incomplete tasks in normal text (please ignore the grouping in the mockup - we don't use grouping).

I need to show all tasks right next to the map.

What possible ways (and their pros and cons) are there to show current and skipped tasks? For instance, would a droplist be better than a listbox, anything else maybe?

[image]

Comment: Well, I would like to get to know more about context of using this app. First if somebody miss the task, will it be fatal for the whole process, e.g. missing check-in, would stop the flight, missing buying in duty free shop would be only missed opportunity to buy gifts.

Answer (score 2):

When deciding how to show the completed and skipped tasks, it is crucial to know how important this information is to the user.
The more important this information is to the user, the more prominent it should be. If the information is less important to the user, it is more appropriate to have the information less obvious, taking up less real estate at first.

**The drop list:**

- Takes up less real estate
- For secondary information, because it is a click or more away from being fully visible

**The listbox**

- Takes up more real estate
- For primary infomration
- Visible immediately

> The user comes to perform the current task.

If the users goal is to perform a task, then it appears that the **completed tasks are secondary information**, and it would be distracting to have them readily available in a listbox.

Another possibility is to have each box *available* to be primary focus, and by ***default***, **have primary focus be uncompleted tasks**.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvqSwy.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You make me think about how quest are designed in games. You should take a look at it, there is probably lots of example on how to show accomplished tasks and current quests.

[image: world of warcraft ui]

*This is just an example, clearly not the best you could find*

I'd suggest a couple of things : use a checkbox, decrease opacity on done task (which are checked), use a color for background and/or text.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAPqBB.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>